# filtered/sanitised form textarea causes MySQL insert to fail

Tags: php

I'm using the below prepared statement to submit data from a form via post
the user data has been filtered and sanitised.  using PHP filter functions  However the insert into MySQL fails on inserting the "Address" value which comes from a text area form input.  I've tried various versions of the data and it seems that any input with newlines "\n\t\r" fails as well as their HTML encoded equivalents. I didn't think these were problamatic for MySQL?  Am I missing the obvious?

Thanks
PS follows:

//DB_Connection

```
            $SP1 = 'call account_register(:Title, :Name, :Surname, :Email, :Mobile, :Password, :Status, :LoginIP, :Token, :TokenExpiry, :Company, :BuildingNumber, :Address, :Street, :City, :County, :PostCode, :ReturnStatus)';
            $Statement = $DBConnection->prepare($SP1);
            #Bind parameters
            $Statement->bindParam(':Title', $_UserData['Title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $Statement->bindParam(':Name', $_UserData['Name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $Statement->bindParam(':Surname', $_UserData['Surname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $Statement->bindParam(':Email', $_UserData['Email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $Statement->bindParam(':Mobile', $_UserData['Mobile'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $Statement->bindParam(':Password', $_UserData['Password'], PDO::PARAM_LOB);
            $Statement->bindParam(':Status', $_UserData['UserStatus'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $Statement->bindParam(':LoginIP', $_UserData['LoginIP'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $Statement->bindParam(':Token', $_UserData['ActivationToken'], PDO::PARAM_LOB);
            $Statement->bindParam(':TokenExpiry', $_UserData['TokenExpiry'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $Statement->bindParam(':Company', $_UserData['Company'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $Statement->bindParam(':BuildingNumber', $_UserData['BuildingNumber'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            //$Statement->bindParam(':Address', $_UserData['Address'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            //$Address = 'line 1&#13;&#10;line 2'; //This is the value of $_USERData after using FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS insert fails
            //$Address = 'Line 1'; //after changing the value of the $_UserData to this the insert is successful
            //$Address = 'line 1&#13;&#10;line 2'; //After extracting from the $_UserData This fails
            $Address = 'Line 1
            line 2
            line 3'; //This fails.  I thought newlines were ok?
            $Statement->bindParam(':Address', $Address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $Statement->bindParam(':Street', $_UserData['Street'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $Statement->bindParam(':City', $_UserData['City'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $Statement->bindParam(':County', $_UserData['County'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $Statement->bindParam(':PostCode', $_UserData['PostCode'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $ReturnStatus = null;   //Return variable for SP must be defined
            $Statement->bindParam(':ReturnStatus', $ReturnStatus, PDO::PARAM_INT | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 1);
            $Statement->execute();
```

Comment: What specific mysql error does this produce?

Comment: It doesnt generate an error so as to speak as its calling a stored procedure.

However the tables the SP are supposed to populate fail and have no data.

Yet if I manually load the" Address" column  with data as can be seen from my post it works perfectly.  It just seems to fail on non alphanumeric characters and newlines...

Answer (score 0):

Well finally got to the bottom of the problem.  retyping the line calling the SP solved it.
I do copy and paste a lot so maybe some miscellaneous unprintable chars got in that line.  That's the only thing I can think as my retype is exactly the same...